# PHP HTML Which is the best video format to display 100 videos

Tags: html

I have around 100 videos to display in my page. The videos are in a folder in the server and the path is saved in the database. The videos are .mov. The page takes more than a minute to load.

I have the freedom to convert the videos to any format I want. (swf,m4v etc). Could anyone tell me which is the lightest file format for videos? The quality of the videos does not really matter. It is just that the page should load faster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do they *have* to be all on the same page?

Comment: yes they have to be in the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to preload all videos will always take some time doesn't matter which format you use. I suggest using thumbnails for each video and link to the player page by clicking on the thumbs. This way the page should load much faster...

Answer (score 1):

Its not about the format of the video....(a little bit) but its also about what video player you use. Most suited would be flv and with something like http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/